# Is there a reason running CI builds on kubernetes cluster?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, devops

I don't know much about kubernetes, but as far as I know, it is a system that enables you to control and manage containerized applications. So, generally speaking, the essence of the benefit that we get from kubernetes is the ability to "tell" kubernetes what containers we want running, how many of them, on which machines, among other details, and kubernetes will take care of doing that for us. Is that correct?

If so, I just can't see the benefit of running a CI pipeline using a kubernetes pod, as I understand that some people do. Let's say you have your build tools on Docker containers instead of having them installed on a specific machine, that's great - you can just use those containers in the build process, why kubernetes? Is there any performance gain or something like this?

Appreciate some insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended to get a good understanding of [what Kubernetes is](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/) and what it can and cannot do.

Generally, containers combined with an orchestration tools can provide a better management of your machines and services. It can significantly improve the reliability of your application and reduce the time and resources spent on DevOps.

Some of the features worth noting are:

- **Horizontal infrastructure scaling**: New servers can be added or removed easily.
- **Auto-scaling**: Automatically change the number of running containers, based on CPU utilization or other application-provided metrics.
- **Manual scaling**: Manually scale the number of running containers through a command or the interface.
- **Replication controller**: The replication controller makes sure your cluster has an equal amount of pods running. If there are too many pods, the replication controller terminates the extra pods. If there are too few, it starts more pods.
- **Health checks and self-healing**: Kubernetes can check the health of nodes and containers ensuring your application doesn’t run into any failures. Kubernetes also offers self-healing and auto-replacement so you don’t need to worry about if a container or pod fails.
- **Traffic routing and load balancing**: Traffic routing sends requests to the appropriate containers. Kubernetes also comes with built-in load balancers so you can balance resources in order to respond to outages or periods of high traffic.
- **Automated rollouts and rollbacks**: Kubernetes handles rollouts for new versions or updates without downtime while monitoring the containers’ health. In case the rollout doesn’t go well, it automatically rolls back.
- **Canary Deployments**: Canary deployments enable you to test the new deployment in production in parallel with the previous version.

However you should also know [what Kubernetes is not](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/#what-kubernetes-is-not):

> Kubernetes is not a traditional, all-inclusive PaaS (Platform as a
> Service) system. Since Kubernetes operates at the container level
> rather than at the hardware level, it provides some generally
> applicable features common to PaaS offerings, such as deployment,
> scaling, load balancing, and lets users integrate their logging,
> monitoring, and alerting solutions. However, Kubernetes is not
> monolithic, and these default solutions are optional and pluggable.
> Kubernetes provides the building blocks for building developer
> platforms, but preserves user choice and flexibility where it is
> important.

Especially in your use case note that Kubernetes:

> Does not deploy source code and does not build your application.
> Continuous Integration, Delivery, and Deployment (CI/CD) workflows are
> determined by organization cultures and preferences as well as
> technical requirements.

The decision is yours but having in mind the main concepts above will help you make it.

Answer (score 0):

An important detail is that you do not tell Kubernetes what nodes a given pod should run on; it picks itself, and if the cluster is low on resources, in many cases it can actually allocate more nodes on its own (via the *cluster autoscaler*).

So if your CI system is fairly busy, and uses all containers for everything, it could make more sense to run an individual build job as a Kubernetes Job.  If you have 100 builds that all start at the same time, it's possible for the cluster to give itself more hardware, and the build queue will clear out faster.  Particularly if you're using Kubernetes for other tasks, this can save you same administrative effort over maintaining a dedicated pool of CI-system workers that need to be separately updated and will sit mostly idle until that big set of builds arrives.

Kubernetes's security settings are also substantially better than Docker's.  Say your CI system needs to launch containers as part of a build.  In Kubernetes, it can run under a *service account*, and be given permissions to create and delete deployments in a specific namespace, and nothing else.  In Docker the standard approach is to give your CI system access to the host's Docker socket, but this can be easily exploited to take over the host.

Comment: Thank you David, for your input. I appreciate it.